# mysql table joining and using DISTINCT

Tags: php, mysql

I am having issues using DISTINCT in mysql as well as joining tables.

I have 2 tables :  tapplicant  and toutcome   They share a APPID which is how i wanted to join them.

I query the tapplicant table and it works fine, i just need 1 columb from the toutcome table called " Status "

I also use DISTINCT in my query as i don't want any duplicate results shown. Below is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT tapplicant.AppDate, tapplicant.Title, tapplicant.FirstName, tapplicant.LastName, tapplicant.Email, tapplicant.Postcode, tapplicant.AppIPAddress, toutcome.Status
FROM tapplicant
INNER JOIN toutcome
ON tapplicant.AppAffID = toutcome.affID;
```

Comment: So what is the question? What is the issue?

Comment: That should work to prevent duplicates. What's the problem? Show some sample input and the expected output.

Comment: `DISTINCT` applies to the whole `SELECT` clause, not just a single column. If you just want a single result for a value in a specific column, use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: May be none of the records are matching your query condition. Try to run it directly in Phpmyadmin and see if it returns any results or shows some error. It will give you some direction.

Comment: The records are there, i have no idea why this does not work. In simple what i need to so is : Get all results from tapplicant table and get one columb " Status " in table toutcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT tapplicant.AppDate, tapplicant.Title, tapplicant.FirstName, 
tapplicant.LastName, tapplicant.Email, tapplicant.Postcode,
tapplicant.AppIPAddress, toutcome.Status FROM tapplicant
INNER JOIN toutcome
ON tapplicant.AppAffID = toutcome.affID;
GROUP BY tapplicant.AppDate, tapplicant.Title,
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `group_concat()` to see what values of `status` are there for the applicant:

```
SELECT a.AppDate, a.Title, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Email, a.Postcode, a.AppIPAddress,
       group_concat(distinct o.Status)
FROM tapplicant a LEFT JOIN
     toutcome o
     ON a.AppAffID = o.affID
GROUP BY a.AppDate, a.Title, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Email, a.Postcode, a.AppIPAddress;
```

That way, if there is more than one, you will know.

Comment: Hi Gordon , thanks, the query works , its just that the toutcome.Status does not display

Comment: @Matt . . . Perhaps the table is empty?  Try with a `left join`.